# Cannot resolve 'gcm' in AndroidManifest.xml when migrating to new GCM protocol for Play Services v7.5+

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

When following the [instructions to migrate an existing app 'that extend a WakefulBroadcastReceiver'](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client), I get an error `cannot resolve gcm` for `com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google omitted the instructions to make sure that, if you are compiling individual `play-services` packages (as recommended), you need to add 
    `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.x.x'` to your `build.gradle`